# How to create project without story board in xcode 6 (swift)?

Tags: swift, xib, xcode6

Can any one has practiced creating project in xcode6 (swift) without storyboard.

I am able to implement

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    var viewController: ViewController? = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    self.window!.rootViewController = self.navigationController

    return true
}
```

but it fails with following error

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 
'-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ViewController" nib but the 
view outlet was not set.'
```

so i tried to relate file's owner UIView with xib, but i am unable to see UIView in file's owner property.

See the screen below

[image]

**EDIT**

Thanks Alex but from the second last point from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder/6395750#6395750) i am unable to find any view.
See the screen attached

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my issue..

See the screen

[image]

Something strange with xcode6 beta, i am not sure whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 6 , you will get two custom class field in file inspector.you should enter your view controller name in second custom class field. when you enter the name then you can see view outlet under file owner properties.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have connected correctly your class with nib file. Especially, `File's Owner` setting. The same steps sequence for Swift as for Obj-C.

Try to reload `XCode` and re-save `.nib` file

See the instructions from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6395750/2429147

or here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17321200/2429147