# Can't set view outlet in xib

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, view, xib, outlet

I have a xib file that includes a view controller but I have the same problem as this link: [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321027/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-exceptionp)

In this answer they can easily set outlet because view has a circle that is clickable.But in my case the view outlet is not even clickable.So I can't set the outlet.What to do now?

Comment: Loading xib like this solved it : `MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    NSArray *nib  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myNibName" owner:self options:nil];
    vc = [nib objectAtIndex:0];`

After this I did not need to set outlet for view.

Comment: I was using `MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myNibName" bundle:nil];` and it was expecting me to set an outlet for the view

Comment: Can you share your project or xib file with .h and .m files? You 100% misconfigured something in Interface Builder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to use `initWithNibName::` is to have a "View" IB document where you have the desired `VC` view outlet as a root element. You need to set the "File's Owner" "Class" to your `UIViewController` subclass and connect it's `view` outlet:
[image]

Also, don't present modal VC from `self` at `viewDidLoad`: at the time of this method execution the VC is often not yet presented itself, `viewDidAppear:` is more fitting for such tests.

Comment: The reason I wrote it in the `viewDidLoad` was to create a quick reference project to show what I meant in the question.But thank you for the "it must be view to use `initWithNibName` " answer.It makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem, but neither this nor any other solutions seemed to work - what I wound up doing was setting the custom class to UIViewController, linking the view as described in the question link, and then changing the class back to the actual custom class name I had intended.  The link stayed and everything worked from that point on.

Comment: What-the-actual-heck!