# Swift: create programmatically UIViewController from xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm approaching to swift in this days and I've a question.

What if I have to create programmatically a new UIViewController?

Easy with an empty/new view controller:

```
var controller: UIViewController = UIViewController()
controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Now, I have a xib file that I would like to load on the controller:

```
var controller: UIViewController = UIViewController(nibName: "FeedDetail", bundle: nil)
controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This crash because:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "FeedDetail" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
```

I've already read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763519/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-new-to-interfacebuilder) and I can't understand what's wrong!

[image]

Comment: your xib file is created but main view of xib haven't connected to it.

Answer (score 3):

Sry I taken the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321027/loaded-nib-but-the-view-outlet-was-not-set-exception),  you missed something like (You have no view in xib so add one and then do this):

[image]

if you are using `Xib` follow this

follo  following steps

> **1) open your xib file then right click on files owner and drag to your first view**

[image]

> **2) then bind that view with outlet of "view"**

[image]

hope you will get it...

Comment: your Viewcontroller created successfully but some outlet is missing

Comment: for quick reference I taken the answer from there, sry